# why do I hit assert in libgit2 when performing remote fetch

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to implement merge with libgit2, and I always hit this assert when performing remote_fetch or create_annotated_commit followed by git_repository_free

But I don't know what I did wrong? And there is no libgit error generated. And I also don't understand the meaning of this assert.

A typical call stack is the following:

```
2  __GI_abort              abort.c       90  0x7f35da541f5d 
3  __assert_fail_base      assert.c      92  0x7f35da537f17 
4  __GI___assert_fail      assert.c      101 0x7f35da537fc2 
5  git_mwindow_put_pack    mwindow.c     106 0x7f35db69725f 
6  pack_backend__free      odb_pack.c    565 0x7f35db6a3dda 
7  odb_free                odb.c         679 0x7f35db69d5c4 
8  git_odb_free            odb.c         696 0x7f35db69d67c 
9  set_odb                 repository.c  95  0x7f35db6d40c3 
10 git_repository__cleanup repository.c  150 0x7f35db6d42a3 
11 git_repository_free     repository.c  161 0x7f35db6d42da 
12 GitEngine::~GitEngine   GitEngine.cpp 268 0x556a9e4f067d 
13 main                    main.cpp      24  0x556a9e4eed8e
```

To reproduce this issue, I simply need to do this:

```
    git_remote *remote;
    int err = git_remote_create(&remote, m_repo, "remotefetch", "./repoD/");
    git_fetch_options fetch_opts = GIT_FETCH_OPTIONS_INIT;
    if (err) {
        qDebug() << "error";
    }
    err = git_remote_fetch(remote, nullptr, &fetch_opts, nullptr);
    if (err) {
        qDebug() << "error";
    }

    if (m_repo) //this is in the destructor 
    git_repository_free(m_repo);
```

if I replace git_remote_create with git_remote_create_anonymous, the issue will be gone.

However, event with git_remote_create_anonymous, if I call git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead later, before git_repository_free , I will hit the same assert again. I have no idea why? I checked the git repository with the command line, the merge seemed to be performed correctly.

Comment: What version of libgit2 are you using?

Comment: Are you ever calling `git_libgit2_shutdown`?

Comment: I'm using the top of tree built directly from the github repo. Yes, I call shutdown, but I need to double check if I called it before or after git_repository_free.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. Yes, it turned out that I mistakenly called shutdown before repository_free. Fixing that resolved the above assert!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen when the library itself has disposed of its internal global state, which is configured with `git_libgit2_init` and destroyed with `git_libgit2_shutdown`.

You *must* call `git_libgit2_init` before calling any libgit2 functions.  You *should* call `git_libgit2_shutdown` when you have finished.  (Though if you're simply shutting down your application, you need not necessarily do so, any open resources will be closed by the operating system.)

However, you *must not* call any libgit2 functions after calling `git_libgit2_shutdown`.  Doing that would attempt to reference freed resources.  Your stack trace suggests that you are calling `git_libgit2_shutdown` before calling `git_repository_free`.

If you reverse the order of those calls then things should be okay.